# How to recover a .memdump.swp~ file

Tags: files

I have a `.memdump.swp~` file. I tried recovering it with `vim -r` but when renaming the file to `.memdump.swp` and then trying `vim -r .memdump` it says that it is not a vim swap file. Using a hexeditor didn't really show anything readable.

If its just a .memdump file, which program could i use to read it?

Comment: What the file should have inside it...?  'cat .memdump | strings' return something?  And what 'file .memdump' returns?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini `cat .memdump | strings` returns nothing ledgible. `file .memdump` returns data